# Excel formula (set using Apache POI) doesn't automatically calculate

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have the following formula in an Excel Cell (Excel 2013)

```
=IF(ROW()>(currentMonths+ROW($A$2)),D7-OFFSET(D7,-currentMonths,0),"")
```

I have written the formulae to the Excel sheet using Java Apache POI. In fact I have used Java Apache POI to loop `currentMonths` from 1 to 12, and each time to recalculate the sheet and this works perfectly. The problem is when I actually load the sheet in Excel, it is then that the recalculation doesn't work.

The code I use to recalculate in Java Apache POI (for 12 months) is as follows:

```
//loop over 12 months
for (int currentMonth = 1; currentMonth <= 12; currentMonth++) {

    //set the month
    CellUtil.getCell(r, 1).setCellValue(currentMonth);

    //recalculate the sheet
    wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();

    //get the result of the recalculation
    double result = CellUtil.getCell(r4, 25).getNumericCellValue();

    //and paste result
    Row r2 = CellUtil.getRow(currentMonth + 4, resultsSheet);
    CellUtil.getCell(r2, 1).setCellValue(result);
}
```

I find that this cell will not recalculate in Excel unless I actually go into the cell and press ENTER - I seem to be having the exact same problem as that experienced in [Excel formulas don't update unless I click on the formula and press enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679424/excel-formulas-dont-update-unless-i-click-on-the-formula-and-press-enter) 
(obviously I have tried Recalculate etc.)

However his resolution does not work for me. Specifically I added the Tab names and set the formulae to be

```
=IF(ROW()>(currentMonths+ROW(Data!$A$2)),Data!D7-OFFSET(Data!D7,-currentMonths,0),"")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you try re-evaluating that cell, as per the [POI Formula Evaluation docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)?

Comment: I have edited my question to describe how the Apache POI recalculation of the sheet works beautifully; the problem is when the sheet is opened in Excel

Comment: How are you recalculating? There's no code added to the question to show it?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the recalculation